# Excel VBA paste from visible cell selection error

Tags: vba, excel

I am still new to VBA, but I am trying to paste a copied selection of rows and columns from a different workbook to the current workbook. My issue is that it errors out when I try to paste I assume because the selection is larger than the destination selection. Below part of the code (I know, horrible and with selects):

```
dim i as long

        Workbooks.Open Filename:="C:\Users\...\File1.xls"
        Range("A15").Select
        For i = 1 To n
            ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=CONCATENATE(RC[1],RC[2])"
            ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
        Next i
        Range("Q15").Select
        For i = 1 To n
        ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC[-16] ,'[file2.xlsm]DST'!C1:C18,1,0)"
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
        Next i
        ActiveSheet.Range("$A$14:$Q$103").AutoFilter Field:=17, Criteria1:="#N/A"
        Range("A1").End(xlDown).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
        Windows("File2.xlsm").Activate
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("sheet2").Activate
        Range("B1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, -1).Select 
        'moves the active cell to the data end of column A
        Debug.Print "Active cell is " & ActiveCell.Address(False, False) 
        'it puts the cursor correctly here, but it errors out after in the selection
        Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
```

Basically, this is part of a code that is adding a new column in a system export file(1), where a unique searching key composed of the second and third column  is used later in a VLOOKUP formula to check if there are any missing products and if there are, those will be added in the reporting file(2), at the end of the data that is there. Column B is used as column A has a formula (another `CONCATENATE` that can't be used for the selection).

How can I make the selection work ?

Answer (score 0):

The following code isn't the solution but it contains it.

```
Dim WbTarget As Workbook
Dim WsT As Worksheet
Dim Rng As Range

Set WbTarget = Workbooks("File2.xlsm")          ' must be open
Set WsT = WbTarget.Worksheets("Sheet2")
Set Rng = WsT.Range("B1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, -1)

With ActiveSheet
    .Range("$A$14:$Q$103").AutoFilter Field:=17, Criteria1:="#N/A"
    .Range("A1").End(xlDown).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy Destination:=Rng
End With
```

Basically, it avoids the `PasteSpecial` method which would require source and target ranges to be of identical size.

Its big flaw is its reference to `ActiveSheet`. You have code here to declare and set a workbook, a worksheet and a range. The target workbook, worksheet and range are never selected or activated. I recommend that you treat the source in the same way.

Set `Option Explicit` at the top of your code sheet. Remember that it is best practice to make all declarations at the beginning of a procedure and, if you like to allow me one more piece of advice, consider writing the results of worksheet functions into your worksheet rather than the worksheet functions.